# Create a wallet with ethereum node

Tags: nodes

If I install the ethereum node on the server, I can create a wallet through it. Now, if I send a transaction from this wallet, do I still have to pay the fee?

In the past, someone told me that if you have a node of a blockchain network on your server, you will no longer need to pay fee for its transactions. I want to know if this is right or wrong

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to pay a fee to have any transaction recorded to the Ethereum blockchain.